# How to use delete method in vue js and laravel api

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

Am using vue js and laravel 5.6 api routes, here is my function

```
removeperson(id){
            var app = this

            fetch(`api/people/${id}`,{
                method: 'delete'
            })
            .then(response=>{

                this.fetchnames();
            })      
        }
```

When I send the request for deleting I got 404 status error, I have tried many solution with no luck

this is my route

```
Route::delete('api/people/{id}','nameController@destroy');
```

Comment: If you want to pass `id` in your url string, than use `fetch('api/people/'+id`. Because you have `id` as `removeperson()` argument. If you get 404, that mean you call wrong url, right? Check what's sending from your request in devs console inside your browser.

Comment: this my resource         Route::resource('people/',  'nameController' ,['except' => ['create','show']]); This what return 404 http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/people/idhere

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list`, you're stil calling wrong url